# Is there some property like 'visible columns' in advance data grid flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I want to some how control the visibility of some columns in my advance data grid. I have a data provider with 115 coumns out of which I want to hide few columns. I know the column index and header field of these columns. Is there some property in Advance data grid where I can specify this directly?

Answer (score 4):

Each column in the **AdvancedDataGrid** is an **AdvancedDataGridColumn**. An **AdvancedDataGridColumn** has a *visible* property which may be set programmatically. Set it to *false* and the column goes away. Set it to *true* and voila, it appears. You may wish to set the *id* property of each **AdvancedDataGridColumn** so you can address it independently.